# How can I get all account info saved in iPhone?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to get information of all logged in accounts like Google, Outlook, iCloud, etc. saved in iPhone (iOS 12).

I found ACAccountStore in Swift to get this info but I can't use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you can't do this.

> These Internet services have been built with the same security goals
>   that iOS promotes throughout the platform. These goals include secure
>   handling of data, whether at rest on the device or in transit over
>   wireless networks; protection of users’ personal information; and
>   threat protection against malicious or unauthorized access to
>   information and services. Each service uses its own powerful security
>   architecture without compromising the overall ease of use of iOS.

From [iOS Security (PDF)](https://www.apple.com/business/site/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf), page 58.

You can obtain data which is "binded" with your app only, and if user allowed access.